# How can I launch particular cells in Jupiter-notebook automatically

Tags: javascript, python, windows, batch-file, jupyter-notebook

I try to launch Jupiter-notebook automatically with code from bat-file opening a file from link. It's a file from an another computer on the same server as mine. I enter password with javascript code, but have no idea what to do with particular cells which I need to launch.

**Attention! Not all cells, but only cells which I need!**

(I know the command Jupiter --nbconvert and --runipy but these ones aren't suitable for me)

Comment: [Notebook Autorun](https://github.com/oscar6echo/notebook-autorun) maybe

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

This is a Jupyter extension that should allow you to auto-run specific cells on startup